# Phpmyadmin to work for php 5.6 and 7.2 both on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php7, magento

I am working on Ubuntu 20.04 and have multiple PHP versions installed (5.6 - 8.0) because I need to work on Magento 1 & 2 both. When I switch to 7.2 and open PHPMyAdmin in the URL, it works fine.

But when I try to switch to PHP 5.6 and refresh PHPMyAdmin page in URL, it goes blank.
I tried with some of the solutions (as attached) but not working.

```
# Copyright (c) 2016, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2.0,
# as published by the Free Software Foundation.
#
# This program is also distributed with certain software (including
# but not limited to OpenSSL) that is licensed under separate terms,
# as designated in a particular file or component or in included license
# documentation.  The authors of MySQL hereby grant you an additional
# permission to link the program and your derivative works with the
# separately licensed software that they have included with MySQL.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License, version 2.0, for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301 USA

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
character-set-server = utf8
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

[my.cnf changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVQ40.png)

```
mysql> 
mysql> use mysql;
Database changed
mysql> 
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root@123';
```

[mysql changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXpFU.png)

Then I restarted MySql and Apache2 both. Can you please help me in this regard?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asking ASAP is a tall order for volunteers. That said, are there any error logs you can look at? They will clearly state why phpMyAdmin isn’t happy with 5.6 

Comment: yes @matigo, I see there as below

cat error.log

PHP Warning:  Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in /usr/share/php/PhpMyAdmin/MoTranslator/Loader.php on line 23
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in /usr/share/php/PhpMyAdmin/MoTranslator/Loader.php on line 116

Comment: Hmm … `strict_types` was added in PHP 7.0.0, which would be why phpMyAdmin is reporting an error when the PHP version is changed to 5.6 

Comment: Yes, I believe so .. strict_types and "??" operator creating prob coz those are not supported in PHP 5.6 so may be need to install phpmyadmin first for php 5.6 and then to try for PHP 7+

Comment: You could do that. However, depending on what you need from a MySQL client, you may want to consider using a tool such as [Beekeeper](https://www.beekeeperstudio.io). It can be found in the Software Store and is a rock-solid SQL editor. This will eliminate the need to work with phpMyAdmin altogether 

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @matigo. Will definitely try that